# React Navigation - How to detect if transition is complete

Tags: react-navigation

I use react-navigation in my app. 
If I navigate from `screen A` to `Screen B`, how can I got some feedback, if the transition is completed.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to clearify your question. So your calling more people with knowledge of this subject.
I also highlight your "screen A & screen B" by surrounding them with ` 
This way your post is easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

`import { InteractionManager } from 'react-native` and then

```
componentDidMount(){
   InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
       //your code
   })
}
```

Comment: Couldn't expect easier and cleaner!